# Format of H.264 decoder configuration record taken from .mp4

Tags: h.264, mp4, codec

I am inspecting decoder configuration record contained in .mp4 video file recorded from Android devices. Some devices have strange or incorrect parameters written in decoder configuration record.

Here is sample from Galaxy Player 4.0 which is incorrect:

```
DecoderConfigurationRecord: 010283f2ffe100086742000de90283f201000568ce010f20
       pictureParameterSetNALUnits : 68ce010f20
       AVCLevelIndication : 242
       AVCProfileIndication : 2
       sequenceParameterSetNALUnits : 6742000de90283f2
       lengthSizeMinusOne : 3
       configurationVersion : 1
       profile_compatibility : 131
       profile_idc : 103
       constraint_set : 16
       level_idc : 0
```

`AVCLevelIndication == 242` is wrong because standard states 51 is the highest value.

`AVCProfileIndication` should be in (66, 77, 88, 100, 120, ..)

`profile_compatibility` is called `constraint_set`?`_flag`s and 2 least significant bits are reserved and seposed to be equal to 0

This is how it should look like:

```
DecoderConfigurationRecord: 0142000dffe100086742000de90283f201000568ce010f20
       pictureParameterSetNALUnits : 68ce010f20
       AVCLevelIndication : 13
       AVCProfileIndication : 66
       sequenceParameterSetNALUnits : 6742000de90283f2
       lengthSizeMinusOne : 3
       configurationVersion : 1
       profile_compatibility : 0
       profile_idc : 103
       constraint_set : 16
       level_idc : 0
```

How can `AVCLevelIndication` and `AVCProfileIndication` be deduced from `profile_idc` and `level_idc` ?

Is there a way to check or possibly fix wrong parameters by comparing them to `SPS` parameters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`level_idc` is `10 * level`.  i.e. if you're using level `3.1`, it will be `31`.

`profile_idc` is specified in Annex A of `ISO/IEC 14496-10`.  Baseline profile is `66`, Main Profile is `77` and Extended Profile is `88` for example.

Additionally, you can see the syntax for the SPS RBSP and PPS RBSP in section 7.3.2.1 and 7.3.2.2 respectively.  Note `ue(x)` and `se(x)` indicate unsigned exponential golomb coding and signed exponential golomb coding.

Edit: My apologies.  The `AVCProfileIndication` and `AVCLevelIndication` should be the same as `profile_idc` and `level_idc`

Comment: in my example profile_idc==103 how that translates to 66 (baseline profile) ? and level_idc==0 how that translates to 13 (level 1.3) ?

Comment: It appears the endianness is backward somewhere along the line.  The `AVCProfileIndication`, `profile_compatibility`, and `AVCLevelIndication` are bytes 1 through 3 in the SPS NALU.  i.e. you should disregard 0x67 because that indicates it's an SPS NALU, and then use `0x42`, `0x00`, `0x0d` for those values.  However, it appears to be using `0xF2`, `0x83`, and `0x02` from the back of the NALU data, and going in the wrong direction.  `0xF2` gives you 242, `0x83` gives you 131 for profile_compatibility, and `0x02` gives you a level of 2.

Comment: Also, this profile_idc == 103 indicates that you're getting profile_idc = 0x67 which is actually the NALU Header.  `0x67 & 0x1F == 0x7` SPS type is 0x7.  You want to start at the next byte, 0x42.

Comment: That is correct. Somehow I would never have noticed such mistake.